# db.sqlite3 continues working after having been deleted

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, sqlite, replit

I recently deleted my `db.sqlite3` file because some data had become corrupted. I though that at the next run of `python manage.py migrate` it would have simply been recreated from stratch. Instead, Django is contuining to work off the old `db.sqlite3` despite the file not existing anymore - I assume it's somehow cached?

Specifically:

- `python manage.py migrate` works fine but it doesn't create a new `db.sqlite3` file.
- There is no `db.sqlite3` file anymore in my root.
- I already manually deleted all migrations.
- The app continues to work okay with all the previous data still there (e.g., users).
- In case it's useful, I'm coding on Replit.

Comment: It does sound like the file is still there. Maybe a stupid question, but are you sure that you deleted the correct file? Maybe you just deleted a backup/copy? Could the file being used be in a sub-folder?

Comment: Could it be a cache issue, meaning, that the file is still available? (because you mentioned using "replit")

Comment: @Ralf I can confirm it doesn't exist, I even search with the find command just in case (but also I see the file is not there). Cache could be an answer, but it doesn't fly: I can also add new rows to the db, which doesn't make sense. I'm... Confused. :)

Comment: A simple/fast solution is to change the name of the file in `settings.py`, so `migrate`-command will create a new file; this does not explain your issue, but it goes around it